# How can I apply an extension method to a datarow column?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, datarow

I have a datarow filled with `int`s stored as `string`s. 
I can parse each one like so: `Convert.ToInt32(row[1].ToString())`

It works, but is a bit unsightly.  I got the idea that maybe I could use an extension class to try and make a `.ToInt` method.  Simplifies things a bit.  After some research, I wrote this up:

```
static class DataRowHelper
{
    public static int ToInt(this DataRow row)
    {
          return Convert.ToInt32( row.ToString());   
    }
}
```

This almost gets me there, but the problem is that it attaches the new method to the row like this: `row.ToInt()`   instead of of attaching it like this:  `row[1].ToInt()`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why aren't you just using a cast?

Comment: So you want to return a single int from an entire `DataRow`?

Comment: you might wanna try row.Field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to apply your own extension method to achieve what you're describing in your question, because the MS team already wrote one for you *(terrybozzio hinted at it in a comment)*.

Instead of using syntax like this:

```
var id = Convert.ToInt32(row[1]);

var id = Convert.ToInt32(row["id"]);
```

There's a strongly-typed `Field` extension method that allows you to specify the data type:

```
var id = row.Field<int>(1);

var id = row.Field<int>("id");
```

I can't imagine you'll get much shorter or clearer than that by writing your own extension method.

Comment: Interesting solution.  This is exactly what I wanted, without mucking around in extension classes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I feel the other answers are offering solutions, but not *answers*.

The *reason* your extension method isn't working is because the return type of the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2549tw02.aspx) of your `DataRow` - `row[1]` isn't a `DataRow`, it's a `string`.

You should enhance your extension method to allow for this indexer:

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{
    public static int ToInt(this DataRow row, int index)
    {
          return Convert.ToInt32(row[index].ToString());   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the column number as a parameter:

```
int i1 = row.ToInt(1);
int i2 = row.ToInt(2);
```

etc.

in which case the extension method would be (error handling not included):

```
public static int ToInt(this DataRow row, int column)
{
      return Convert.ToInt32(row[column].ToString());   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better if you want to handle generics and DbNull:

```
static class DataRowHelper
{
    public static int ToInt(this object item)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(item == null ? 0 : item);
    }
}
```

This is not very exception-safe, and will throw on quite a few conditions.  You might want to add some checking here, or implement a `TryToInt()` type method.

Comment: Just use `object` instead of `T` - no need for generics here.

Comment: @DStanley: You absolutely *can* have a generic static class - it's just that it can't have extension methods in it.

Comment: @JonSkeet good point - this works on its own, but not as an extension method.  Do I just need to remove the `static`?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 No, it has to be static to be an extension method as you probably know.  Either make the _method_ generic instead of the class or remove the generics altogether.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 remove the `<T>` (like Jon said :)

Answer (score -2):

Your extension method should inherit a `string`, not a `DataRow`.  It should look like this (keep in mind this is very simple... and you should probably include error handling of some sort):

```
static class DataRowHelper
{
    public static int ToInt(this string item)
    {
          return Convert.ToInt32(item);   
    }
}
```

Comment: If you wanna be fancy, it should really be `this T item` ;)

Comment: `this object item` if you really want to go all out, but I simplified things for him.